# Understand PdfCleanUpProcessor

Tags: itext

In iText, when a PdfCleanUpProcessor is used, are the respective objects edited inline or are new objects appended at the end of the PDF so that when it is rendered, the new object is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not changed or added objects are *appended at the end of the PDF* depends on how you construct the `PdfStamper`:

- If you construct it in `append` mode (using `true` as fourth constructor argument), any changes or additions are appended at the end and the original objects all remain in the file.
- Otherwise the order of the content might change considerably, added indirect objects are written fairly early, changed indirect objects might be written anytime, unused objects are removed.

Thus, concerning your question:

> when a PdfCleanUpProcessor is used, are the respective objects edited inline or are new objects appended at the end of the PDF so that when it is rendered, the new object is displayed?

**You decide!** It's up to your choice of using or not using the `append` mode.

As the `PdfCleanUpProcessor` is intended in particular for redaction use cases, though, the former option often makes no sense...

---

There is a catch, though: PDF is a very versatile format. In particular you can create PDFs in which multiple objects (pages, form xobjects, ...) share the same content stream.

Thus, iText cannot manipulate the existing content stream but has to create a new one to replace the old one for a redacted object - in a case of shared content streams the information marked for redaction in one of those objects might not be marked for redaction in another and consequently has to remain in the original stream.

Usually this is no problem: If the information is marked for redaction in all uses of the stream, the original stream becomes unused and, therefore, eventually is removed. And if the information is not marked for redaction in some uses of the stream, the information obviously was meant to remain there.

But! Not all uses of the content stream necessarily show the *whole* stream content. They even could show *exclusive sections* of the content stream! In that case the person marking the PDF for redaction would most likely only mark the occurrence of the data on the page on which it is visible but not on the other pages on which it is off-screen. In such a case the information would remain in the redacted file in the off-screen area of those other pages.

I have not yet inspected the source code of the iText 7 cleanup module, neither have I tested it for such a case. So I cannot say whether that improved version of the `PdfCleanUpProcessor` has taken precautions to deal with this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. That helped a lot :D